# Trying to optimize graph query on massive table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to query a huge table quickly for graph statistics. Here's how I'm forming my graph data. Day is on the x-axis and amount is the y-axis.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, COUNT(earning_link_id) AS amount  from earnings where earning_link_id = 1093
GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)
```

**Took 21.8s....earnings has about 550,000 rows.**

I'm currently in the process of setting up a read replica server, but that is just brute force, not an elegant query approach.

I wonder how I can optimize this type of query, so we can get graph data quickly?

Comment: looks like the table is missing the index and most likely on `earning_link_id` you can check the existing indexes as `show indexes from earnings` and if the col `earning_link_id` is not indexed, add an index as `alter table earnings add index earning_link_id_idx(earning_link_id)`, make sure to take a backup of the table before applying index.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it's a live server so I guess I have to take it down for maintenance too then?

Comment: You have ~550,000 rows into the table so adding an index would take some time to built the index and then transfer to real memory, this would create a read lock for a while, however if the server is strong enough you can do directly without having to shut the site down. But make sure you took the table backup before applying the index.

Comment: I think I'll take it down anyway just to be sure - so basically you mean make a duplicate of the table?

Comment: Also does the indexed column have to be unique values for me to make index or can I have duplicates?

Comment: Indexes have nothing to do with uniqueness (which is the job of PRIMARY KEY)

Comment: No just take a dump of the table, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the table may be lacking of index.

The most obvious is `earning_link_id` as it's a column used in your `where` condition.

As a side note when you have performance issues on requests and/or you want to optimize them, use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. It will show you how MySQL scans your table to answer your query. If your table has no index for the filtered columns (*where condition*) it will scan all rows which is really costly; whereas with an index on `earning_link_id` MySQL don't need to scan the whole table to find all affected rows (*for this query*).

Comment: Yep...my system is working like greased lighting now.....I seem to have prematurely optimized the hardware......oh well....I can always downgrade and save money now :))))

Comment: Thanks for the tips on EXPLAIN I will have to check that out!!

Comment: are UNIQUE columns also indexed? Or do I need to apply an index to them as well?

Comment: Yes, UNIQUE columns are usually indexed